# Compile error "incompatible types"

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap

I have compile error:

```
Error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String.
```

at line `String buf = it.next();`

```
public String getMostFrequentColor() {
    HashMap<String, Integer> colors = countColors();
    int count = 0;
    String mfcolour;
    Iterator it = colors.keySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String buf = it.next();
        if (colors.get(buf) > count) {
            count = colors.get(buf);
            mfcolour = buf;
        }
    }

    return mfcolour;
}
```

I don't have any Idea why this could happen. `it.next()` should return a String in my opinion.

Comment: As an aside, it would be simpler to use `for (String key : colors.keySet())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting `String` to prevent this problem at compile time. The compiler gives you this warning simply because Java is a strict-typed language. At runtime, if the variable cannot be cast, you will only run into problems then.

```
String buf = (String) it.next();
```

Or you could make it more specific by specifying the type of `Iterator` you want to use. This is probably the better option.

```
Iterator<String> it = colors.keySet().iterator();
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `Iterator<String>` instead of `Iterator`.

```
Iterator<String> it = colors.keySet().iterator();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using an `Iterator` without a generic argument. This means that it will return `Object` types. Either amend its declaration (by turning `Iterator it` into `Iterator<String> it`) or manually cast the object retrieved by `it.next()`.
The latter may be subject to type-safety issues though!

Answer (score 1):

The return type of the `next()` method in the `Iterator` class is `Object`.  Since you know that your `HashMap` has a key set of type `String`, you'll need to cast the result of `it.next()` to `String`:

```
String buf = (String) it.next();
```

Comment: It would be far cleaner just not to use the raw `Iterator` type, using `Iterator<String>` instead.

Comment: Jon's suggestion (and that of others) of declaring the iterator as `Iterator<String>` is even better -- the cause is the same but the solution is slightly different and doesn't require casting.  The advantage is that it can be type-checked at compile time, so if later you try to assign `it.next()` to something other than a `String` the compiler will scream at you about it :-)